# How to set time limit for retrieveing files from FTP server in groovy?

Tags: groovy, ftp, filemaker

How to set the time limit here for retrieveing files from FTP server.If the files not able to get within time imit then through 
        an error called timeout exception with error code.If files get within timelimit then get successful message.

```
      import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient
      import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
        import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
       import groovy.io.FileType
       start()
       def start(){

        def store;
        int TENSECONDS  = 10*1000
        int THIRTYSECONDS = 30*1000
        def ftpClient = new FTPClient()
        try{

            ftp.setSoTimeout(THIRTYSECONDS)     
            ftp.setConnectTimeout(TENSECONDS)
            ftpClient.connect(server)
            ftp.setDefaultTimeout(TENSECONDS)
            ftpClient.login(user,pass)
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode()
            FTPFile[] fileslist = ftpClient.listFiles("/")
            FTPFile[] folderfileslist = ftpClient.listFiles("/sample")
            FTPFile[] folderfileslist1 = ftpClient.listFiles("/sample1")

            def allFiles = []; 
            for(int i=0; i<fileslist.length; i++){  
            String file_name = fileslist[i].getName()
            String file_timestamp = fileslist[i].getTimestamp().getTime()     
            String s = '|' + file_name+ '|' + '/' +file_name+'|'  +file_timestamp
            allFiles << s       
          }               
        return allFiles.join('\n')
  }
  catch?(Exception e){
    return e.printStackTrace(); 
  }
  finally{

       ftpClient.disconnect()
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `FTPClient`? Apache Commons? How is the question related to `filemaker`?

Comment: please check my updated question .yes It's an Apache.From the above code I'm able to get all files from FTPServer.How to set time out for retrieving files from FTP.

Comment: see the documentation: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html there are a lot of `set*Timeout` methods

Comment: please check my updated question is there any error.please verify once

Answer (score 0):

You may try the AST in groovy:

import groovy.transform.TimedInterrupt

```
//timeout of 10 seconds
        @TimedInterrupt(value = 10L, unit = java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS) 
        def start(){
           […]
           try{
              //block that eventually may hang
           }catch(TimeOutException e){
              //handle the exception
           }
           […]
    }
```